# extra storage on ubuntu vps

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, vps

I have a vps that runs Ubuntu 16.04.3 that came with 10 GB storage, but later I added 100 GB cloud storage to it but the problem is 10 GB drive is mounted on root directory(/) and 100 GB drive is mounted on the sub directory. so I can't do anything because my 10 GB drive is full but my 100 GB drive is almost empty.

I think if I can mount my additional storage to root and set boot flag on it and un mount the 10 GB drive it might work but I want to be sure.

Comment: Will your VPS automatically move the Ubuntu install to the 100 GB volume?

Comment: No,So i have to move the operating system to 100 GB volume